# What is Community Wiki and are these kinds of questions the right ones to propose?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

There are two questions I have asked which may benefit from being wiki's where everyone can improve upon the general advice.

I have heard the term "community wiki" being banded about but have no idea where this is or how it works.

If it is just as it sounds then the two proposals would be:

[Where can I find the full list of Google/Microsoft CDN hosted AJAX files?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/where-can-i-find-the-full-list-of-google-microsoft-cdn-hosted-ajax-files)

and

[What are the hard and fast rules for Cache Control?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/what-are-the-hard-and-fast-rules-for-cache-control) *(if enough information can be centrally collated on the matter)*

Is community wiki a sensible option? If so how do you go about setting it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki can be turned on for any post by checking the community wiki checkbox within the question.  You will find it right under where you enter the body.

The purpose of community wiki is to allow anyone to edit the question and to create questions where no penalties or benefits are created for voting the question or the answers up or down.  So you won't get any rep for votes on your community wiki questions or answers.

The main use for community wiki is for questions where there is no 1 "correct answer".  Usually questions like "What X do you prefer to use to do/solve Y." or "What is your favorite Z."

Comment: Thank you - I have now made both questions a community wiki.

Comment: @Metalshark: I'm not sure those two posts should be CW. I mean, the answer I posted on the cache control question may not be the only solution, but it is a solid answer for most people. There may be other answers that are correct, but each one would be specific to a set-up or situation.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - I understand your point, and yes it is a solid answer. However with the myriad of gauntlets caching headers have to run, it was of personal benefit for all to edit the question, improving the list of hard & fast rules, or propose techniques without fear of loosing reputation if they didn't work out. Admittedly I was in the wrong for not starting the question as CW, in which case my intentions would have been clear. I did not notice the Community Wiki option (bottom right - out of eye line) until @RandomBen pointed it out here.